# Using PowerShell to upload to AWS S3

Tags: powershell

Hopefully this is a quick fix (most likely user error) I am using PowerShell to upload to AWS S3, I'm attempting to copy x amount of .mp4s from a folder to an S3 location, I'm able to copy individual files successfully using the below command:

```
aws s3 cp .\video1.mp4 s3://bucketname/root/source/
```

But when I try to copy all the files within that directory I get an error:

```
aws s3 cp F:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\* s3://bucketname/root/source/

The user-provided path F:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\* does not exist.
```

I've tried multiple variations on the above, no path just *, *.mp4, .*.mp4 (coming from a Linux background, using quotation marks etc) but I can't seem to get it working.

I was using this documentation initially https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-copy-folder-contents-in-powershell-with-recurse-parameter I feel the answer is probably very simple but couldn't see what I was doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you want the `--recursive` parameter so `aws s3 cp F:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 s3://bucketname/root/source --recursive` to do multiple files

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, seems so blindingly obvious now you mention it. Appreciated!

Comment: It's only ever obvious once you know its there